# Java Mac ZoneInfoMapping error

Tags: java, macos

I've just updated to jre 1.6, and I'm not sure if this is a result of upgrading or not, but I'm getting this error whenever I run my app:

ZoneInfo: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/zi/ZoneInfoMappings (No such file or directory)

I tried going back to 1.5, but the error is still there, and after a fair amount of google time, haven't really found out what the issue is, or how to fix it.

If anyone has come across this before and can point me in the right direction that would be great.

thanks

Comment: I came across this after a bit more searching: 
"The second error message is due to the file ZoneInfoMappings being missing in /usr/share/zoneinfo; it exists in the original JavaVM framework zoneinfo files. So you might try copying it from zi.old to zi, but I'm skeptical that this will solve the problem." Im just trying to locate the original JavaVM framework zoneinfo files, but am not sure where these are?

Answer (score 0):

Apple just came out with Java Update 5, which seemed to fix the problem.  Just run Software Update and it should install the update.

Comment: I've already installed that update and hasn't seemed to have helped.